# Why redirect output doesn't work in multiprocessing?

Tags: python, logging

I am using facebook prophet to forecast future salecount. 
There is a problem that pystan which prohpet depended would output optimizer messages while training .

I found a way to stop that annoying message from  https://github.com/facebook/prophet/issues/223#issuecomment-310497971  , but it only work if you run it in main process .

func:

```
def func():
   with suppress_stdout_stderr():
     p = Propet(*kwargs).fit(training_data)
```

If running in multiprocess like :

1. joblib

   ```
   Parallel(n_jobs=process_num)(
       delayed(func)(pid) for pid in pids
   )
   ```
2. multiprocessing

   ```
   with Pool(1) as p:
       r = p.map(func, pids)
   ```

The annoying log messages would still print.

I have tried to mute it by

```
def mute():
    sys.stdout = open(os.devnull, 'w')  

with Pool(1, initializer=mute) as p:
    r = p.map(func, pids)
```

Without success .

Comment: Remember that every process has its own `stdout`.

Comment: @Klaus D Sorry, I am not familiar with how process working in underlying level . Could you give me a favor ?